# How does the lu( ) function decide what to return?

Tags: matlab, matrix, decomposition

Let `A` be the following matrix:

```
1 3 
2 4
```

if I call the `lu( )` function and save the return values like this:

```
[L, U] = lu(A);
```

MATLAB returns L, U such that L * U = A:

```
>> L * U

ans =
     1     3
     2     4
```

While when I save the return values like this:

```
[L, U, P] = lu(A);
```

L * U is **not** equal to A:

```
>> L * U

ans =
     2     4
     1     3
```

because `lu( )` returns L, U, P such that `L * U = P * A`

My questions:

- **How can the `lu( )` function know how many return parameters I have asked for?**
- **Can I replicate this behavior in my code?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) function to detect how many output arguments have been requested.

In addition, you can use [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) to fill your argument list appropriately.

For example:

```
function varargout = myfun(a,b)

    switch nargout
        case 1
            varargout{1} = a;
        case 2
            varargout{1} = b;
            varargout{2} = a;
    end

end
```

When called with one output argument, the first (and only) output will be `a`. When called with two, the first will be `b`, the second `a`.

You can also use `nargoutchk` (or in older versions `nargchk`) to assert that the number of output arguments requested is within specified limits.

`lu` does something similar to this, but is implemented in compiled C rather than MATLAB.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be replicated using [`varargout`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html). Similarly you can use [`varargin`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) if you want variable number of inputs.

```
function varargout = my_fun(a,b,c);
   varargout{1} = b;
   varargout{2} = c;
   varargout{3} = a;
end

Now, this function can be called

x = my_fun(1,2,3)
x = 2

[x, y] = my_fun(1,2,3)
x = 2
y = 3

[x, y, z] = my_fun(1,2,3)
x = 2
y = 3
z = 1
```

As Sam Roberts points out, this does not help you create a function that behaves differently for different numbers of outputs. If that's what you want, you should check out [`nargout`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) in combination with a [switch-statement](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/switch.html). Similarly, you can use [`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) if you want to alter the behavior depending on the number of input variables. Please check out [Sam Roberts' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22834665/2338750) to see how this can be done.

Comment: This doesn't demonstrate how to change the behaviour of a function depending on the number of outputs (as requested by OP), only how to fill fewer or more outputs.